# Lo Shu Magic Square always returning false

Tags: python

This is what I am trying to do:

The Lo Shu Magic Square is a grid with 3 rows and 3 columns, as shown below. The Lo Shu Magic Square has the following properties:

The grid contains the numbers 1 through 9 exactly.

The sum of each row, each column, and each diagonal all add up to the same number.

In a program you can simulate a magic square using a two-dimensional list. Write a function that accepts a two-dimensional list as an argument and determines whether the list is a Lo Shu Magic Square. Test the function in a program.
4   9   2
3   5   7
8   1   6

For testing purposes you should send in two two-dimensional lists: one is a Lo Shu Magic Square, the other is not.

**I am trying to get the program to return as True, but even with the correct numbers above it still outputs False everytime. Any help would be greatly a Here is my code:**

```
def numOfRowsAndColumns(inp2DList):
    numOfRows = len(inp2DList)
    numOfColumns = len(inp2DList[0])
    return numOfRows, numOfColumns

#This function processes the individual numbers by row and column by adding
#them together.
def getRowSum(inp2DList, numOfColumns):
    firstRowSum = 0
    for currentRow in range (1):
        for currentColumn in range (numOfColumns):
            firstRowSum += firstRowSum + inp2DList[currentRow][currentColumn]
    return firstRowSum

#These functions returns a true/false value based on equality of Rows & Columns.
def equalRows (inp2DList, firstRowSum, numOfRows, numOfColumns):
    rowSum = 0
    for currentRow in range (numOfRows):
        for currentColumn in range (numOfColumns):
            rowSum = rowSum + inp2DList[currentRow][currentColumn]
        if rowSum != firstRowSum: 
            return False
        rowSum = 0      #resets rowSum to 0
    return True

def equalColumns (inp2DList, firstRowSum, numOfRows, numOfColumns):
    columnSum = 0
    for currentColumn in range (numOfColumns):
        for currentRow  in range (numOfRows):
            columnSum = columnSum + inp2DList[currentRow][currentColumn]
        if columnSum != firstRowSum:
            return False
        columnSum = 0       #resets columnSum to 0
    return True

#This function acts as a check against the previsous equalColumns &
#equalRows functions.
def equalRCSums(inp2DList,firstRowSum,numOfRows,numOfColumns):
    if equalRows(inp2DList,firstRowSum,numOfRows,numOfColumns)\
         and equalColumns(inp2DList, firstRowSum,numOfRows, numOfColumns):
        return True
    else:
        return False
#These functions do the same thing as the previous ones, except diagonally.
def leftEqDiagonalSum(inp2DList,randLengthAnyRC,firstRowSum):
    leftDiagonalSum = 0
    for currentDiagonalNum in range (randLengthAnyRC):
        leftDiagonalSum = leftDiagonalSum + \
            inp2DList[leftEqDiagonalSum, currentDiagonalNum]
    if leftDiagonalSum != firstRowSum:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def rightEqDiagonalSum(inp2DList,randLengthAnyRC,firstRowSum):
    rightDiagonalSum = 0
    currentDiagonalNumColumn = randLengthAnyRC - 1
    for currentDiagonalNumRow in range (randLengthAnyRC):
        rightDiagonalSum = rightDiagonalSum + inp2DList[currentDiagonalNumColumn][currentDiagonalNumRow]
        currentDiagonalNumColumn = currentDiagonalNumColumn - 1
    if rightDiagonalSum != firstRowSum:
        return False
    else:
        return True

#This function returns true or false based on the diagonal sums of the
#numbers in the list.
def eqDiagonalSums(inp2DList, randLengthAnyRC, firstRowSum):
    if eqDiagonalSums(inp2DList,randLengthAnyRC, firstRowSum)\
         and eqDiagonalSums(inp2DList, randLengthAnyRC, firstRowSum):
        return True
    else:
        return False

#This functuon determines if the list given is a Lo Shu Magic Sqaure.
def isThisALoShu(inp2DList, firstRowSum, numOfRows, numOfColumns, randLengthAnyRC):
    if equalRCSums(inp2DList, firstRowSum, numOfRows, numOfColumns)\
        and eqDiagonalSums(inp2DList, randLengthAnyRC, firstRowSum):
        return True
    else:
        return False



#This main function takes the sample list and will tell you if it's
#a magic square or not.
def main():
    inp2DList = [[4,9,2],[3,5,7],[8,1,6]]
    numOfRows, numOfColumns = numOfRowsAndColumns(inp2DList)
    randLengthAnyRC = numOfRows
    firstRowSum = getRowSum(inp2DList, numOfColumns)
    if isThisALoShu(inp2DList, firstRowSum, numOfRows, numOfColumns,randLengthAnyRC):
        print("This is a Lo Shu Magic Square!")
    else:
        print("This is NOT a Lo Shu Magic Square, please try again.")

main()
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: We expect you to start the debugging process, rather than handing us 100 lines of code with only "it always returns False".  *where* in the intermediate processing does it differ from what you expected, and what do  you not understand about that segment of code?

Comment: Sorry for the block of code. I think I'm running into a problem in the main or the isThisALoShu function. All of the numbers equal 15 every way you add them. I'm not sure where I went wrong but it always returns "This is NOT a Lo Shu Magic Square, please try again.", No matter what the numbers are. I found that If I switch the true and false variable in the isThisALoShu then it outputs that it is a Lo Shu, but again it will say that with any number you put in. Kind of out of my depth here.

Comment: Where is the requested trace?  As you say, the numbers add to 15 in every direction, but nowhere do you verify even that much in your code.  See this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).

Answer (score 0):

So it was just a few typos in the code the first example is the getRowSum() function.

```
def getRowSum(inp2DList, numOfColumns):
    firstRowSum = 0
    for currentRow in range (1):
        for currentColumn in range (numOfColumns):
            firstRowSum += firstRowSum + inp2DList[currentRow][currentColumn]
    return firstRowSum
```

returns 36 as the first row sum which is why it always returns false in the end. the code should actually be.

```
def getRowSum(inp2DList, numOfColumns):
    firstRowSum = 0
    for currentRowIndex in range(1):
        for currentColumnIndex in range(numOfColumns):
            firstRowSum = firstRowSum + inp2DList[currentRowIndex][currentColumnIndex]
    return firstRowSum
```

which will return 15. The next issue was with eqDiagonalSums() in there you actually created a recursive function that calls itself infinitely you just didnt realize it because your code never got to that point. finally you had given leftEqDiagonalSum() a tuple instead of:

```
for currentDiagonalNumber in range (randLengthAnyRC):
    leftDiagonalSum = leftDiagonalSum +\
        inp2DList[currentDiagonalNumber][currentDiagonalNumber]
```

Here is the full code that ran just fine. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
def numOfRowsAndColumns(inp2DList):
    numOfRows = len(inp2DList)
    numOfColumns = len(inp2DList[0])
    return numOfRows, numOfColumns

#This function processes the individual numbers by row and column by adding
#them together.
def getRowSum(inp2DList, numOfColumns):
    firstRowSum = 0
    for currentRow in range(1):
        for currentColumn in range(numOfColumns):
            firstRowSum = firstRowSum + inp2DList[currentRow][currentColumn]
    return firstRowSum

#These functions returns a true/false value based on equality of Rows & Columns.
def equalRows (inp2DList, firstRowSum, numOfRows, numOfColumns):
    rowSum = 0
    for currentRow in range(numOfRows):
        for currentColumn in range (numOfColumns):
            rowSum = rowSum + inp2DList[currentRow][currentColumn]
        if rowSum != firstRowSum:
            return False
        rowSum = 0      #resets rowSum to 0
    return True

def equalColumns (inp2DList, firstRowSum, numOfRows, numOfColumns):
    columnSum = 0
    for currentColumn in range(numOfColumns):
        for currentRow  in range (numOfRows):
            columnSum = columnSum + inp2DList[currentRow][currentColumn]
        if columnSum != firstRowSum:
            return False
        columnSum = 0       #resets columnSum to 0
    return True

#This function acts as a check against the previsous equalColumns &
#equalRows functions.
def equalRCSums(inp2DList,firstRowSum,numOfRows,numOfColumns):
    if equalRows(inp2DList,firstRowSum,numOfRows,numOfColumns)\
         and equalColumns(inp2DList, firstRowSum,numOfRows, numOfColumns):
        return True
    else:
        return False
#These functions do the same thing as the previous ones, except diagonally.
def leftEqDiagonalSum(inp2DList,randLengthAnyRC,firstRowSum):
    leftDiagonalSum = 0
    for currentDiagonalNumber in range (randLengthAnyRC):
        leftDiagonalSum = leftDiagonalSum +\
            inp2DList[currentDiagonalNumber][currentDiagonalNumber]
    if leftDiagonalSum != firstRowSum:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def rightEqDiagonalSum(inp2DList,randLengthAnyRC,firstRowSum):
    rightDiagonalSum = 0
    currentDiagonalNumColumn = randLengthAnyRC - 1
    for currentDiagonalNumRow in range (randLengthAnyRC):
        rightDiagonalSum = rightDiagonalSum + inp2DList[currentDiagonalNumColumn][currentDiagonalNumRow]
        currentDiagonalNumColumn = currentDiagonalNumColumn - 1
    if rightDiagonalSum != firstRowSum:
        return False
    else:
        return True

#This function returns true or false based on the diagonal sums of the
#numbers in the list.
def eqDiagonalSums(inp2DList, randLengthAnyRC, firstRowSum):
    if rightEqDiagonalSum(inp2DList,randLengthAnyRC, firstRowSum)\
         and leftEqDiagonalSum(inp2DList, randLengthAnyRC, firstRowSum):
        return True
    else:
        return False

#This functuon determines if the list given is a Lo Shu Magic Sqaure.
def isThisALoShu(inp2DList, firstRowSum, numOfRows, numOfColumns, randLengthAnyRC):
    if equalRCSums(inp2DList, firstRowSum, numOfRows, numOfColumns)\
        and eqDiagonalSums(inp2DList, randLengthAnyRC, firstRowSum):
        return True
    else:
        return False



#This main function takes the sample list and will tell you if it's
#a magic square or not.
def main():
    inp2DList = [[4,9,2],[3,5,7],[8,1,6]]
    numOfRows, numOfColumns = numOfRowsAndColumns(inp2DList)
    randLengthAnyRC = numOfRows
    firstRowSum = getRowSum(inp2DList, numOfColumns)
    if isThisALoShu(inp2DList, firstRowSum, numOfRows, numOfColumns,randLengthAnyRC):
        print("This is a Lo Shu Magic Square!")
    else:
        print("This is NOT a Lo Shu Magic Square, please try again.")

main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, you're a real life wizard. I was beginning to walk away for a bit and come back. I read through your code and implemented the changes and it seems to work. What was wrong with it if you don't mind explaining?

Comment: so the first problem was the getRowSum() was returning 36 instead of 15 because you used += instead of =. += takes the sum of the value on the left and the value on the right and assigns it to the value on the left. that was the biggest one. the next one was within eqDiagonalSums() in that function you make it call itself which enters an infinite loop. So I changed the function calls to be rightEqDiagonalSum and leftEqDiagonalSum. finally, I made a quick correction to lefttEqDiagonalSum. You fed the summing function a tuple instead of two separate elements so I fixed that and it worked

Comment: Just remember to do a little debugging prior to posting a good way to do it by hand is to explicitly print all variables and print out a flag of some sort to determine how far your program gets before it fails and where it may be deviating from whats expected.

Comment: Well you definitely were a great help. I attempted to do a little debugging before I came to stackoverflow, but I am quite new at to programming so I wasn't getting very far. Reading through your explanation now it makes a lot more sense to me as to why it wasn't working. I will definitely be reviewing the differences between our codes side by side so I can learn from this. Thanks again for your help man!